# Remote access(headless) ubuntu desktop in first boot

Tags: raspberrypi, remote-access, 20.10

I have raspberry pi 4. I had ubuntu server 20.04 on which from first boot i can have remote access(headless) . Now i have installed ubuntu desktop 20.10 . I have laptop with windows 10(but no separate keyboard and mouse)(i have 1 separate monitor only) . how can i operate my pi with laptop with help of ethernet cable or local wifi or any other cable from first boot? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you upgraded from 20.04 to 20.10, the IP address should still be the same and you should be able to access it the same way as you did before through ssh, if that is how you accessed it.  If you clean installed it, I don't think the desktop version comes with ssh enabled by default and you would have to find a way to get a keyboard and mouse to it somehow.

Comment: Oh, i formatted 20.04 and then installed 20.10

Comment: Is there any way to enable ssh by adding any file to sd card

Comment: If you start with the Server first as the install you can get it configured for the ssh connection as it starts by default.  Then after you can install the Desktop you want.  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#1-overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Terrance's comment is spot on. Follow the instructions at https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi for installing the server.

On step 5 (**Install a desktop**), I elected to use the regular desktop instead of one of the lightweight ones, so I just ran `sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop`. So far, the Raspberry Pi 4 seems up to the task.

I could not get VNC working, so I instead installed **xrdp** and used a Remote Desktop client to connect to it. When I connected, it wanted me to finish some setup tasks, and that might be why it was being difficult with VNC.

Comment: Yes, its right i also think initial setup dont allow remote access.For desktop u will atleast once need all the hardware once setup done there is gnome-ssh prebuilt in ubuntu20.10 it starts with boot u will just need to install OpenSSH n might not make any issue later.

Comment: Yeah, I removed the last sentence from my answer about enabling VNC. I noticed that from the Remote Desktop view, I could not enable VNC. I guess, as you say, it may be because I have no hardware hooked up, other than a power supply.